# Obtener la multiplicación de dos valores en una variable en asp.net core mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo una tabla donde tengo dos valores, la cantidad de un producto y el precio, y quiero obtener el total de la multiplicación de esos dos valores que es igual a (total=cantidad*precio), he visto que se puede hacer de la siguiente manera en la clase de la carpeta Models a la hora de crear la tabla mediante migración:

```
   public class Factura
{ 

    public int FacturaID { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }

    public decimal Total ()
    {
        return Cantidad * Precio;
    }
```

}

Este es el codigo de mi controlador en las vistas index y Create:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Factura.ToListAsync());
    }

  public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Facturas/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FacturaID,Cantidad,Precio")] Factura factura)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(factura);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(factura);
    }
```

Buscando en internet vi que se puede hacer de esa forma, pero cuando hago la migración y creo el controlador, no obtengo el total, debo hacer alguna acción o consulta en el controlador para obtener el resultado o que deberia hacer, si hay otra forma de hacerlo?  Necesito de su ayuda!! Porfavor!!

Comment: Como es tu controlador?

Comment: @gbianchi actualize la pregunta y agregue los datos del controlador

Comment: Y podrias aclarar en que parte no viene el total?

Comment: En donde te lo omite?

Comment: En la accion Create,  public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FacturaID,Cantidad,Precio")] por ejemplo agrega a los demas campos nos al total, es como si fuera invisible

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar un ViewModel. Por ejemplo:

```
public class FacturaVM
{ 

    public int FacturaID { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }
}
```

Y en tu controlador lo recibes:

```
    // POST: Facturas/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(FacturaVM facturaVM)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            // Realizas el mapeo de los datos
            var factura = new Factura
            {
                FacturaID = facturaVM.FacturaID,
                Cantidad = facturaVM.Cantidad,
                Precio = facturaVM.Precio
             };

            _context.Add(factura);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(factura);
    }
```

De esta manera cuentas con el valor del total protegido.

Como recomendación, si tienes un valor que es calculado en base a otros, no utilices un método, sino una propiedad, es decir, en tu clase Factura podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
public class Factura
{ 

    public int FacturaID { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }

    public decimal Total 
    {
        get{ return Cantidad * Precio;}
    }
}
```